# Why can't I insert datas in multiple rows in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

```
INSERT INTO doctor (doc_id,doc_name,doc_speciality,doc_available,doc_info) values
    (5,'Jack Racheal','Gastric','yes','No one'),
    (6,'Yara Greyjoy','Respiratory problems','yes','Daughter of Balon Greyjoy'),
    (7,'Jared','Cancer','yes','Mastermind behing the Silicon Valley'),
    (8,'Avaiato','Respiratory problems','yes','Daughter of Howland Reed',
    (9,'Leo DiCaprio','Diabetes','yes','Django Unchained'),
    (10,'Danerys Targareyan','Respiratory problems','yes','Mother of Dragons'),
    (11,'Jon Snow','Jaundice','yes','Knows nothing'),
    (12,'Tyrion Lannister','Typhoid','yes','Knows something when he drinks'),
    (13,'Samwell Tarly','Gastric','yes','Step father of baby sam'),
    (14,'Cateyln Tully','Respiratory problems','yes','Red wedding'),
    (15,'Sandors Clegane','T.B','yes','The hound'),
    (16,'Arya Stark','Cholera','yes','The girl has no name')
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Why can't you?  Do you get an error?  What is the problem?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13

Answer (score 1):

id 8 is:

```
(8,'Avaiato','Respiratory problems','yes','Daughter of Howland Reed',
```

It seems to be missing a closing paren.

```
(8,'Avaiato','Respiratory problems','yes','Daughter of Howland Reed'),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon!